# Playing game results in not true colors

Tags: rendering, game-engine

When I play the game, it doesn't appear with true colors

Original image:
[image: image Original]

When I play game:
[image]

There are no trees and 3D Text is not true color.
What happened?

Comment: Do you have *Stereo* enabled in *Properties >  Render Settings*? Try setting it to *None*

Comment: I noticed the analglyph mode too. What do you mean with "true color"? Or do you refer to missing parts of the scene? Beside of that there is way to less information to give you any advice.

Comment: @gandalf3 thank you. Your answer is the best answer.

Comment: @Monster Um.. True color is When I played games. It distorted color images from the color of the Material. Example  "Hackerdew" Text is white color. But when I played game is blue and red color. 

Well What is call this color distorted? 
But now I can get an answer. Thank you

Comment: That explains it. thank you. 1 point for gandalf3's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have *Stereo* enabled and set to *[Anaglyph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D)*. This mode is intended for use with red/cyan 3D glasses, which enables the viewer to perceive depth in the game. See the relevant [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D).

If you don't want this enabled, set it to *None* in *Properties > Render Settings > Stereo*:

[image]